# An Interesting Property Concerning a Sequence of Integers

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A non-decreasing sequence of positive integers $a_1,a_2,\dots a_n\ (n\geq 3)$ is *good* if for each $3\leq k\leq n$ there are $1\leq i\leq j<k$ such that $a_i+a_j=a_k$.

Let $\ell,m$ be positive integers, and consider the set $[\ell]=\{1,2,\dots,\ell\}$. We say that $[\ell]$ is of type $P(m,1)$ if for any partition of $[\ell]$ into $m$ non-empty disjoint subsets $S_1,\dots,S_m$, there exists an $i\leq m$ such that one can choose, possibly with repetition, some elements in $S_i$ to form a *good* sequence. Otherwise $[\ell]$ is of type $P(m,0)$.

Let $f(m)$ denote the smallest positive integer of type $P(m,1)$. My question is, what is $f(3)$?

I managed to prove that

$\bullet$ if $\ell$ is of type $P(m,0)$, then so are $1,2,\dots,\ell-1$

$\bullet$ if $\ell$ is of type $P(m,1)$, then so are $\ell+1,\ell+2,\dots$

$\bullet$ $f(1)=2$

$\bullet$ $f(2)=5$

Indeed, note that $[4]=\{1,4\}\cup \{2,3\}$. So $4$ is of type $P(2,0)$, and therefore so are $1,2,3$. Now assume that some $n\geq 5$ is of type $P(2,0)$ and that $[n]=S_1\cup S_2$, where $S_1,S_2$ are non-empty disjoint subsets of $[n]$. WLOG, $1\in S_1,2\in S_2$. (Note that if $1,2$ are in the same $S_i$, then there would be a good sequence $1,1,2$.) Let $r$ be the largest element in $S_1$. If $r=1$, then $2,4\in S_2$ but $2,2,4$ is a good sequence. So $r>1$. If $r<n$, then $r+1\leq n$ and $r+1\in S_2$. Thus, $r-1=(r+1)-2\not\in S_2$, meaning that $r-1\in S_1$. Now $1,r-1,r$ is a good sequence in $S_1$, a contradiction. Therefore, $r=n$. But then $n-1=r-1\not\in S_1$. So $n-1\in S_2$, and $n-3=(n-1)-2\in S_1$. Finally, $3=n-(n-3)\in S_2$, and $5=2+3\in S_1$. Then $4=5-1\in S_2$, creating a good sequence $2,2,4$. We conclude that any $n\geq 5$ is of type $P(2,1)$.

$\bullet$ $12<f(3)$ (because $[12]=\{1,3,10,12\}\cup \{2,5,8,11\}\cup \{4,6,7,9\}$)

$\bullet$ $f(m)\leq \left[\sum_{j=0}^m\frac{1}{j!}\right]m!\ \forall m\geq 1$ (which follows from a repeated use of pigeonhole principle)

In particular, $13\leq f(3)\leq 16$

But I'm not able to see if $13,14,15$ are of type $P(3,1)$. So any help is appreciated. Thanks!

I'm also wondering if the following holds.
$$f(m)=\left[\sum_{j=0}^m\frac{1}{j!}\right]m!\ \forall m\geq 1$$
Equivalently, is it true that
$$(m+1)f(m)+1\leq f(m+1)\ \forall m\geq 1$$

Comment: @antkam No. A sequence of at most two terms is not good. $f(1)=2$ because in the set $\{1,2\}$ you can choose $1,1,2$ to form a good sequence. $f(2)=5$ because if you assume that $f(n)$ is of type $P(2,0)$ for some $n>4$ and that $[n]=S_1\cup S_2$, then either $1\in S_1,2\in S_2$ or vice versa (since otherwise you would have a good sequence $1,1,2$ from the same $S_i$). Then consider the largest element in the $S_i$ which contains $1$. Divide into cases and derive a contradiction.

Comment: yeah, after typing my comment, i re-read and realized you can pick repeats.  thats why i deleted it right away.  but pls leave your comment up (or better yet: incorporate these examples into the main text).  fun problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! Actually this problem is basically [Schur's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_theorem). The upper bound given by the finite sum is far from tight. For instance, when $n=5$, the Schur number [is shown to be](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.08076.pdf) $160$.

And it can be shown by graph coloring that when $n=3$, the Schur number is $13$.

Answer (score 1):

Partial solution: $f(3) \neq 13$ because $\{1,4,7,10,13\}, \{2,3,11,12\}, \{5,6,8,9\}$

Note the first part is $1 \pmod 3$, and we certainly cannot get a good sequence out of that.  I wonder if that's a generally good approach...

Comment: Thanks. Actually I tried this but found it a bit hard to control the lower bound. If we have a set of the form $\{2^n\cdot b_1,2^n\cdot b_2,\dots,2^n\cdot b_k\}$, where $b_1,\dots,b_k$ are odd integers and $n$ is any positive integer, we can never find a good sequence out of the set because $2^n\cdot (b_i-b_j)=2^n\cdot \text{an even number}$. Similarly, let's consider partitioning elements of $[n]$ based on their remainders mod $m$. For $0\leq i<m$, let $A_i=\{a\in [n]:\ a\equiv i\pmod m\}$. Then it is easy to see that when $i>0$, no $A_i$ contains any good sequence.

Comment: The tricky part is $A_0$. You can, by computing the highest power of $2$ dividing $n$, partition $A_0$ into a certain number of sets, none of which contains any good sequence.

Comment: And indeed we can see some patterns in your example (and mine). $[12]=\{1,3,10,12\}\cup \{2,5,8,11\}\cup \{4,6,7,9\}$. Note that $1+12=3+10=2+11=5+8=4+9=7+6=13$. Analogously, $[13]=\{1,4,7,10,13\}\cup \{2,3,11,12\}\cup \{5,6,8,9\}$, and $1+13=4+10=7+7=2+12=3+11=5+9=6+8=14$.

Comment: The issue with using $A_i$ is that the results are generally kinda weak.  E.g. since $4$ is $P(2,0)$, we immediately have, using mod $3$, that $14$ is $P(4,0)$ by using $A_1, A_2$ and then partitioning $A_0 = \{3,6,9,12\}$ ala $[4]$.  But while $14$ is $P(4,0)$ is kinda interesting, that sheds no light on the more interesting question of whether $14$ is $P(3,1)$ or $P(3,0)$...

Comment: Here are my final thoughts before temporarily giving up. For each $m\geq 1$, there exists a partition $S_1,\dots,S_m$ of $[f(m)-1]$ such that one cannot extract any good sequence from any $S_i$. We call such kind of partitions 'bad'. For any bad partition and any $i\leq m$, there are $a,b\in S_i$ such that $a+b=f(m)$. Indeed, suppose not. Then for any pair $p,q\in [f(m)-1]$, $|p\pm q|\neq f(m)$ . So we can insert $f(m)$ in any $S_i$ without generating good sequences, meaning that $f(m)$ is $P(m,0)$, a contradiction. For each $f(m)-1$, is there a unique bad partition in the following sense?

Comment: 1. Each block in a bad partition is saturated, or maximal, meaning that for each $i\leq m$ and each $a\in [f(m)-1]\setminus S_i$, there is at least one good sequence $S_i\cup \{a\}$. 2. $S_1,\dots,S_m$ is a partition of $\{(k,f(m)-k):1\leq k<f(m)\}$.